# Use sed command with substring to replace

Tags: sed, substring, regexp-substr

I am looking to use the sed command to replace a substring value.

I have a file like this

```
UNIT56712423MP000000R0990
```

The records in this file are always of the same length.

I need to check if the 21st character is `R`, then replace characters 13-14 from `MP` to `GH`.

Is there a way I can achieve this through the sed command?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Answer: Yes. Please, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask]. You won't get anyone here to do your homework for you if you don't even show a minimal amount of effort.

Comment: If you have a problem with a regex, please show the regex so that we could help you fix it,

Comment: Thanks for the help.. i did it with using perl

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed

```
sed -E '/^\w{20}R\w{4}$/s/^(.{12})../\1GH/' <<<UNIT56712423MP000000R0990
```